# Is it appropriate to drive traffic here from Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, etiquette

This is a question about Stack Exchange etiquette in relationship to [salesforce.stackexchange.com](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com) being in the public beta stage. As new salesforce related questions show up at Stack Overflow, is it acceptable to recommend that the person asking the question try posting it over here as well?

It seems like a good way to increase traffic, but I'm not sure if that would be appropriate.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I will add that this also includes webapps : I asked a q on the meta, http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1164/tag-request-salesforce and was directed to here. I assume it's fine to direct SF related q's to here.

Answer (score 7):

For questions that are off-topic at Stackoverflow, i think its fine to point them this way, but if the question is on-topic for Stackoverflow i think it should be left as is, at least for the time being.

Comment: That feels right to me too, and it's what I'll do for now. But with the blessing of higher-level moderators, it would be nice to let people who are asking related questions know that this new site is even available to them.

Answer (score 3):

I think I ended up here because someone posted a link to this place at Stackoverflow...so yes why not :)

Answer (score 2):

I think that if they are Salesforce related questions it is fine for them to be asked/answered on StackOverflow for now without someone telling them they should be doing it here and not there.

However, if you see them you should definitely comment about this site and suggest that they try asking their *next* question here.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do it for every Salesforce-related question, but good questions or questions that could become good with little work are worth inviting to Salesforce Stack Exchange.